# PHP output echo as text when using a header

Tags: php

I am trying to do a loading bar in php, AJAX or anything JS related can't really be used.

It works alright displaying numbers or words as it loads

```
    echo $text;
    echo str_pad('', 4096) . "\n";

    ob_flush();

    flush();
```

but the problem is it displays everything in simple text.

As a result I can't add any CSS or HTML to my view through echo.
I have included this header in order to make flush work and actually update my page as it loads.

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
```

Answer (score 0):

The header you are using is not actually going to parse as HTML/CSS.

What you need is actually something like:

```
 ob_implicit_flush( true );
```

And then normally like above

```
ob_start();

while (true) {
    echo "Something is going on!";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

That's how I do it in most projects. Now if this doesn't work there might be some cache in your web server. I hit that issue many times. To avoid that this helps:

```
header( 'X-Accel-Buffering: no' );
header( 'Content-Encoding: none' );
```

Comment: Deleting header('Content-Type: text/event-stream'); makes the real time updating not work, even after using your code

Comment: That's interesting, may I ask what web server/php module are you using? As in does the PHP run as module, fpm or fcgid?

Comment: I am trying to implement this at work and we use custom everything here
Edit: and I have no idea what exactly

Comment: I see. Well based on my experience the above always solves the issue. I did once hit that sort of issue with apache but there the only fix was adding
` -flush`
to the .conf file where wrapper path was set so e.g.:
`FCGIWrapper "E:/Web/main/bin/engine.exe -flush -c ./../config/engine.ini" .php`